# How to extract names form the same excel sheet that have failed in both subjects

Tags: excel

If you have an excel sheet containing the results of students, list the process you would perform to extract the students that have failed in both science and math. (Assuming pass marks is 50) *

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
=AND(B1<50,C1<50)
```

Which would give true for both fails, assuming A1 has the name, B1 has maths result and C1 has science result.

Then you might wish to sort the list and work from there.

There are other ways of looking at things but you don't show any data that we can even check.